# data streaming on gRPC python with iterator request but get "Exception iterating requests!"

Tags: python, streaming, grpc

I tried to use gRPC python to make a bidirectional streaming communication, but there is some issue on client side request...

Here is my proto:

```
service ABC {
    rpc DataTransmission (stream DataTransmissionRequest) returns (stream DataTransmissionResponse);
}

message DataTransmissionRequest {
    bytes data = 1;
    string ticket = 2;
}

message DataTransmissionResponse {
    bytes data = 1;
}
```

Here is my client code for generating a iterator request and call the dataTransmission function

```
def generateRequests():
        req_msgs = [
            (b"123", "sySJZDV9Rb8dyqt1"),
            (b"123"),
            (b"123"),
            (b"123"),
            (b"123"),
            (b"123"),
        ]
        iter = 0
        for (req, ticket) in req_msgs:
            print("(req, ticket) = ", (req, ticket))
            if iter == 0:
                request = ABC_pb2.DataTransmissionRequest(data=req, ticket=ticket)
            else:
                request = ABC_pb2.DataTransmissionRequest(data=req)
            iter += 1
            print("iter = ", iter)
            yield request

    #my_queue = queue.SimpleQueue()
    with grpc.insecure_channel(addr) as channel:
        stub = ABC_pb2_grpc.ServiceProxyStub(channel)

        data_transmission_resp = stub.DataTransmission(generateRequests())
        print("data_transmission_resp = ", data_transmission_resp)
        ##print("data_transmission_resp = ", list(data_transmission_resp))
        ## use the results
        for data_trans in data_transmission_resp:
            print(data_trans)
```

but got the error

```
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
        details = "Exception iterating requests!"
        debug_error_string = "None"
```

Why this error? and is this the right way to use bidirectional gRPC communication on python?

Then, there are some posts mentioning the following way:

```
    my_queue = queue.SimpleQueue()
    with grpc.insecure_channel(addr) as channel:
        stub = ABC_pb2_grpc.ServiceProxyStub(channel)

        my_queue.put(generateRequests())
        data_transmission_resp = stub.DataTransmission(iter(my_queue.get, None))
```

Also the same error...

Answer (score 1):

`Exception iterating requests!` means there is an Exception raised by the request iterator. I would recommend to add a try-catch clause to see what's wrong.

Comment: Not sure why a try-catch would help surface an error. If the gRPC library is not raising the exception outside of the library, by the time a user gets to the code where this is shown (.details()), the exception doesn't happen. I'm getting this before iterating over the iterator. TLDR: We can't catch an exception which doesn't happen.

Comment: Using OP's snippet as an example, it's possible to add a try-catch in `generateRequests`. When a generator is passed to another library, technically, there is no guarantee which thread it will be iterated on, which makes the correct point of raising this exception vague. If you think this is important, feel free to post issues to github.com/grpc/grpc.

Answer (score 1):

*For those who are intending the rpc to be unary-stream instead of stream-stream:*

I had the same error when I had unfortunately declared my stream to be `stream-stream`, but I was using it like a `unary-stream`. I just had to fix my message and regenerate the code.